# Verify fooX is subset of foo using hash fingerprints

Tags: hash, cryptography

I have got a big audio file foo and a hash file h with h = sha256sum(foo);
Third parties can check the integrity of foo provided h is published somewhere.

I now want the third party only to have parts of foo. However they shall be able to verify these parts being a subset of (the unpublished) foo.
Generally speaking:
Considering `File foo = foo0.concat(foo1).concat(foo2).....concat(fooN);`

Exists a Function where `func(sha256sum(foo)) == func(sha256sum(foo0),....,sha256(fooN))` ?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Can you describe a use case/ultimate aim?

Comment: You might be able to achieve something like this with a [hash length extension attack](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks)